# Disable address bar in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to disable the address bar in IE9. I've done a significant amount of searching on this and just can't seem to find a way to make it happen. A lot of web resources discuss how to do it in IE8, but not IE9.

The reason you might ask? I have an application being hosted in a remote desktop farm that links to web pages outside of the application into Internet Explorer. I need to ensure users are limited to just going to the pages the program pushes them to. I realize I could use a proxy server to limit where they can go, but I'm trying to find a really simple way to just disable the address bar instead.

I can't use Kiosk mode because it puts the browser into full screen mode. This won't work for my situation as I need to give users what appears to be a regular browsing experience without an address bar.

Comment: I believe almost all the browsers these days pretty much force you to have an address bar for security reasons.

Comment: @Zoredache - By default, for public sites yes. See my answer below re: default settings for the Trusted Sites.

Answer (score 2):

If you control the application, you have a couple of options.

If it's web-based, you could launch the URL without a location to menubar using a JavaScript link like:

```
window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank','location=0,menubar=0');
```

[Window open() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

However, depending on the zone (Internet, Local Intranet, or Trusted) the pages are located, this may or may not be allowed by default. You can either add the sites to the Trusted Sites list, where the default is to allow, or change the setting 'Allow websites to open windows without address or status bars' to Enable under your Trusted Site Security Settings.

If it's not web-based, you could use the above or a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) object embedded in the application (or a similar object as implemented in whatever  language/framework you are using).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run it in Kiosk Mode by doing `iexplore -k`.

Comment: I've gone down this route. The problem is kiosk mode puts the browser into full screen. I need a regular browsing experience without an address bar.

Comment: Do the proxy approach, then. If it were an open source browser you could hack it into submission, but it's going to be a lot of work getting IE to do something odd like this.

Comment: If you are developing code, then you can hack something up relatively easily to embed an Internet Explorer object in the .NET languages.